# Let $n$ be an integer. Then $n^2-3n+6$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble with questions that ask me to prove something, for example:

> Let $n$ be an integer. Then $n^2-3n+6$ is even.

Should I go about it using direct proof-method involving cases or should I go about it using proof by contrapositive?

Comment: What method have you tried?  Have you checked what happens whe $n = 2k$ for some integer k (n is even), and then checked what happens when $n = 2m+1$ for some integer m (i.e. n is odd)?  You can use either route; If you assume there exist n such that $n^2 -3n+ 6$ is odd, where does that lead you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT**

**First Way - Brute Force**

Note that $$n^2-3n+6$$ is even if and only if $n^2-3n$ is even.

1. What happens if $n$ is even (i.e. $n=2k$ for some integer $k$)?
2. What happens if $n$ is odd (i.e. $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$)?

---

**Second Way - Factorization**

Note that
$$
n^2-3n+6 = (n-1)(n-2) + 4
$$
Can you show directly that both terms of the sum are always even?

Comment: Great answer, would like to give +1 but I used up my votes :(.

Comment: So the first way would be using cases?  Case 1 and case 2.

Comment: @piza25 yes, indeed

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to $n^2\equiv n \,(\text{mod}\, 2)$, and you can check that it holds for $n=2k$ ($n$ even) and $n=2k-1$ ($n$ odd).